Long table to fit in two pages
I have the following table which is too long and needs to be split on 2 pages, but currently it is not split.
I suspect that tabular inside tabularx causes the issue.
How to fix this?
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\textwidth= 5.00in
\textheight= 7.4in
\topmargin = 30pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=55pt
\headsep=17pt
\parskip=.8pt
\parindent=12pt
\font\smallit=cmti10
\font\smalltt=cmtt10
\font\smallrm=cmr9
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}    % For reducing margin
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\usepackage{ltablex}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} 


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Name}
\begin{tabularx}
\footnotesize 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllllllllllllllll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Time}} & \multicolumn{16}{c}{Place} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-17} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{15} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{16}\\ 
\midrule
2007, I& 0 &\\
2007, II& 0 &\\
2007, III& 0 &\\
2007, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2008, I& 0 &\\
2008, II& 0 &\\
2008, III& 0 &\\
2008, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2009, I& 0 &\\
2009, II& 0 &\\
2009, III& 0 &\\
2009, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2010, I& 0 &\\
2010, II& 0 &\\
2010, III& 0 &\\
2010, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2011, I& 0 &\\
2011, II& 0 &\\
2011, III& 0 &\\
2011, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2012, I& 0 &\\
2012, II& 0 &\\
2012, III& 0 &\\
2012, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2013, I& 4 &\\
2013, II& 0 &\\
2013, III& 0 &\\
2013, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2014, I& 0 &\\
2014, II& 0 &\\
2014, III& 0 &\\
2014, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2015, I& 0 &\\
2015, II& 0 &\\
2015, III& 0 &\\
2015, IV& 1 &\\
\hline
2016, I& 0 &\\
2016, II& 0 &\\
2016, III& 0 &\\
2016, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2017, I& 0 &\\
2017, II& 0 &\\
2017, III& 0 &\\
2017, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2018, I& 1 &\\
2018, II& 1 &\\
2018, III& 1 &\\
2018, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2019, I& 1 &\\
2019, II& 0 &\\
2019, III& 0 &\\
2019, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2020, I& 0 &\\
2020, II& 0 &\\
2020, III& 0 &\\
2020, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2021, I& 0 &\\
2021, II& 0 &\\
2021, III& 0 &\\
2021, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2022, I& 0 &\\
2022, II& 0 &\\
2022, III& 0 &\\
2022, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2023, I& 0 &\\
2023, II& 0 &\\
2023, III& 0 &\\
2023, IV& 0 &\\
\hline
2024, I& 0 &\\
2024, II& 0 &\\
2024, III& 0 &\\
2024, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}



you get ! Missing number, treated as zero. as you have not use the width argument or the column specificationargumennt oftabularx. Remove the tableandtabularxenviornment and changetabulartolongtable`

no latex document should have \font command why would you have a primitive font loading for computer modern when you have specified that the document use latin modern?

As @DavidCarlisle has remarked in a comment, you should be employing a longtable environment.

\documentclass{article} % '10pt' is the default
% I've tried to reduce the preamble to a sensible minimum
%%\parskip=.8pt  % you can't be serious
\parindent=12pt
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath} %%%{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb} %%%{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{longtable} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next 4 instructions
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % see section 5 of user guide of 'longtable' package
\setlength\LTright{0pt}% 

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{16}{c}}

\caption{Name}\\
\toprule
\multirow{2.3}{*}{Time} & \multicolumn{16}{c}{Place} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-17} 
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{17}{l}{Table \thetable, cont'd}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
\multirow{2.3}{*}{Time} & \multicolumn{16}{c}{Place} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-17} 
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{17}{r}{\footnotesize(cont'd on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

2007 I  & 0 &\\
2007 II & 0 &\\
2007 III& 0 &\\
2007 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2008 I  & 0 &\\
2008 II & 0 &\\
2008 III& 0 &\\
2008 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2009 I  & 0 &\\
2009 II & 0 &\\
2009 III& 0 &\\
2009 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2010 I  & 0 &\\
2010 II & 0 &\\
2010 III& 0 &\\
2010 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2011 I  & 0 &\\
2011 II & 0 &\\
2011 III& 0 &\\
2011 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2012 I  & 0 &\\
2012 II & 0 &\\
2012 III& 0 &\\
2012 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2013 I  & 4 &\\
2013 II & 0 &\\
2013 III& 0 &\\
2013 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2014 I  & 0 &\\
2014 II & 0 &\\
2014 III& 0 &\\
2014 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2015 I  & 0 &\\
2015 II & 0 &\\
2015 III& 0 &\\
2015 IV & 1 &\\
\midrule
2016 I  & 0 &\\
2016 II & 0 &\\
2016 III& 0 &\\
2016 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2017 I  & 0 &\\
2017 II & 0 &\\
2017 III& 0 &\\
2017 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2018 I  & 1 &\\
2018 II & 1 &\\
2018 III& 1 &\\
2018 IV & 0 &\\
%\midrule
2019 I  & 1 &\\
2019 II & 0 &\\
2019 III& 0 &\\
2019 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2020 I  & 0 &\\
2020 II & 0 &\\
2020 III& 0 &\\
2020 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2021 I  & 0 &\\
2021 II & 0 &\\
2021 III& 0 &\\
2021 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2022 I  & 0 &\\
2022 II & 0 &\\
2022 III& 0 &\\
2022 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2023 I  & 0 &\\
2023 II & 0 &\\
2023 III& 0 &\\
2023 IV & 0 &\\
\midrule
2024 I  & 0 &\\
2024 II & 0 &\\
2024 III& 0 &\\
2024 IV & 0 &\\

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}



tabular* cannot be split across pages.
table is never split across tables.

I believe you're misunderstanding the working of ltablex.
Aside, don't juggle with parameters such as \evensidemargin: using geometry is much easier and avoids errors. Besides, you're actually loading geometry…
The package amstext is a subsidiary of amsmath, better to load the big one.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  textwidth=5in,
  textheight=7.4in,
  headsep=17pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % to make \footnotesize local
\footnotesize 

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l *{16}{X}@{}}
\caption{Name} \\ \endfirsthead
\midrule\endhead
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Time} & \multicolumn{16}{c}{Place} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-17} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{15}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{16}\\ 
\midrule
2007, I& 0 &\\
2007, II& 0 &\\
2007, III& 0 &\\
2007, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2008, I& 0 &\\
2008, II& 0 &\\
2008, III& 0 &\\
2008, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2009, I& 0 &\\
2009, II& 0 &\\
2009, III& 0 &\\
2009, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2010, I& 0 &\\
2010, II& 0 &\\
2010, III& 0 &\\
2010, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2011, I& 0 &\\
2011, II& 0 &\\
2011, III& 0 &\\
2011, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2012, I& 0 &\\
2012, II& 0 &\\
2012, III& 0 &\\
2012, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2013, I& 4 &\\
2013, II& 0 &\\
2013, III& 0 &\\
2013, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2014, I& 0 &\\
2014, II& 0 &\\
2014, III& 0 &\\
2014, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2015, I& 0 &\\
2015, II& 0 &\\
2015, III& 0 &\\
2015, IV& 1 &\\
\midrule
2016, I& 0 &\\
2016, II& 0 &\\
2016, III& 0 &\\
2016, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2017, I& 0 &\\
2017, II& 0 &\\
2017, III& 0 &\\
2017, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2018, I& 1 &\\
2018, II& 1 &\\
2018, III& 1 &\\
2018, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2019, I& 1 &\\
2019, II& 0 &\\
2019, III& 0 &\\
2019, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2020, I& 0 &\\
2020, II& 0 &\\
2020, III& 0 &\\
2020, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2021, I& 0 &\\
2021, II& 0 &\\
2021, III& 0 &\\
2021, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2022, I& 0 &\\
2022, II& 0 &\\
2022, III& 0 &\\
2022, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2023, I& 0 &\\
2023, II& 0 &\\
2023, III& 0 &\\
2023, IV& 0 &\\
\midrule
2024, I& 0 &\\
2024, II& 0 &\\
2024, III& 0 &\\
2024, IV& 0 &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\endgroup

\end{document}



For completeness of possible solutions: an example of employ longtblr of tabularray. Using it the table code is a bit shorter, group of years are separated by bigger vertical space:
\documentclass{article} % '10pt' is the default
% I reduce the preamble to minimum neded for this table
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularray} % <-- new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{\footnotesize\itshape}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachfour} % for inserting additional vertical space between groups of years
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {7}{4}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Name},
  label = {longtab:?}
                ]{colsep = 3pt,
                  colspec = {@{} l *{16}{X[c]}},
                  cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
                  cell{1}{2} = {c=16}{},
                  row{3-Z} = {rowsep=0.5pt},
                  row{eachfour} = {abovesep=1.1ex},% for row groups separations
                  rowhead = 2
                  }
% column headers
\toprule
Time    &   Place
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &     \\ 
\midrule
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16  \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
% table body
2007, I  & 0 &\\
2007, II & 0 &\\
2007, III& 0 &\\
2007, IV & 0 &\\

2008 I  & 0 &\\
2008, II & 0 &\\
2008, III& 0 &\\
2008, IV & 0 &\\

2009, I  & 0 &\\
2009, II & 0 &\\
2009, III& 0 &\\
2009, IV & 0 &\\

2010, I  & 0 &\\
2010, II & 0 &\\
2010, III& 0 &\\
2010, IV & 0 &\\

2011, I  & 0 &\\
2011, II & 0 &\\
2011, III& 0 &\\
2011, IV & 0 &\\

2012, I  & 0 &\\
2012, II & 0 &\\
2012, III& 0 &\\
2012, IV & 0 &\\

2013, I  & 4 &\\
2013, II & 0 &\\
2013, III& 0 &\\
2013, IV & 0 &\\

2014, I  & 0 &\\
2014, II & 0 &\\
2014, III& 0 &\\
2014, IV & 0 &\\

2015, I  & 0 &\\
2015, II & 0 &\\
2015, III& 0 &\\
2015, IV & 1 &\\

2016, I  & 0 &\\
2016, II & 0 &\\
2016, III& 0 &\\
2016, IV & 0 &\\

2017, I  & 0 &\\
2017, II & 0 &\\
2017, III& 0 &\\
2017, IV & 0 &\\

2018, I  & 1 &\\
2018, II & 1 &\\
2018, III& 1 &\\
2018, IV & 0 &\\

2019, I  & 1 &\\
2019, II & 0 &\\
2019, III& 0 &\\
2019, IV & 0 &\\

2020, I  & 0 &\\
2020, II & 0 &\\
2020, III& 0 &\\
2020, IV & 0 &\\

2021, I  & 0 &\\
2021, II & 0 &\\
2021, III& 0 &\\
2021, IV & 0 &\\

2022, I  & 0 &\\
2022, II & 0 &\\
2022, III& 0 &\\
2022, IV & 0 &\\

2023, I  & 0 &\\
2023, II & 0 &\\
2023, III& 0 &\\
2023, IV & 0 &\\

2024, I  & 0 &\\
2024, II & 0 &\\
2024, III& 0 &\\
2024, IV & 0 &\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


